# grouping of date data with a condition in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a csv file with several variables, as illustrated below (just for example):

```
Region    crop      product    date_periode

A         aaaa      bilon      2016052q

A         aaaa      mailon     2016021q 

B         cccc      drox       2016042q

A         cccc      marob      2015081q

C         dddd      salon      2016062q

C         dddd      dilon      2016071q

D         aaaa      daxon      2015032q

D         aaaa      bayon      2016042q
```

the dates are periods : 20170502q : the seconde half of mai 2017 
and i want to do a grouping individuals per crop and region such as every time the number of individuals for a date for a crop in a region is less than 5% of the total number of individuals with the same date for a crop in a region this date is grouped with the adjacent date (the date, in this case, can become 2016062q-2016071q if we group the two periods for example), and every time for each culture in each region.
if we have this table for exemple :

```
region    crop       date         Numbre of ID    % of ID

A         aaaa    20170201q         1             1

A         aaaa    20170202q        44            48

A         aaaa    20170301q        30            33

A         aaaa    20170302q        14            15

A         aaaa    20170401q         1             1

A         aaaa    20170402q         1             1

A         aaaa    20170601q         1             1
```

i want to arrive to have this one after analysing

```
region      crop      date                    Number of ID      % of ID

A           aaaa      20170201q-20170202q         45              49

A           aaaa      20170301q                   30              33

A           aaaa      20170302q-20170601q         17              18
```

I don't know if I'm clear enough but I'm here if you have any questions above, thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide an expected output?

Comment: I would love to help you, but it is unclear what you mean: "5% of the total number of individuals" --> what is the number of individuals here?

Comment: @Georgery : for exemple if you take region = A and crop = aaaa, the total number of individuals is = 2 for this crop in this region, that means every date hase 50% of individuals for this crop in this region we can keep the dates without change, what i want to do in the other cases to see for every date for each crop in every region if the total individuals for each dates is more than 5% of the total number of individuals for a crop in region if it's not the case i must group some individuals ( dates ) to be able to have more than 5 %

Comment: @akash87 I added another example above thanks

Comment: What is `number of id`?

Comment: @akash87: number of ID : number of individuals for each crop in each region

Comment: Is it number of distinct individuals? Or just total individuals? In my code I used `n_distinct` because I thought it was distinct individuals

Comment: @akash87 total individuals

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` we can do this using:

```
df %>% 
group_by(Region, crop, date_periode) %>% 
summarise(number = n_distinct(product)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
left_join(  df %>% 
            group_by(Region, crop) %>% 
            summarise(number_t = n_distinct(product)) %>% 
            ungroup(), by = c("Region", "crop")) %>% 
mutate(Percent = number/number_t)
```

I think this is what you are getting at? I am assuming `Number` is the total distinct `product`.